# How to display whole QString while debugging

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I am using Qtcreator and always when I need to display large string, it's trimmed, see screenshot:
[image]

Is there any way to display whole QString? Note that using Open view contents in editor doesn't help either, it's same there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a setting under "Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> (Locals & Expressions or General (depending on your creator version))" that limits the string length to default 10000 characters.

Comment: Under the Tools -> Options -> Debugger settings, the "Maximum string length: 10000" is the maximum length for strings in separated windows. The setting right below it, "Display string length: 100" is the maximum length for string entries in the Locals and Expressions pane. Editing the latter is the solution to this question.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52298088/9256941

"In Local and Expressions, right click on the variable and click on
Change Value Display Format, then under Change Display for type
QString click on Separate Window"

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a limitation of the Qt Creator UI that cuts the displayed length of strings.

`qDebug() << yourString;`  seems to work for me, I can see my whole string in the application output panel :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, I tried on my machine with a 150000 characters string and the same happened... It seems that qDebug() has the same limitation.
I would suggest you to output your string to a file, using fstream for example.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem with debugging, isn't there a way to make it work directly in qtcreator so that I don't have to store the string somewhere else to view it runtime?

Answer (score 0):

None of the above change that a `QString` is displayed simply as an address, along with all its useless cryptic members.

However, if you right-click on the variable in the debugging panel, and click on "Use Debugging Helpers", all the contents of the string are displayed. Hoorah.

Answer (score 0):

Right-clicked on the "class Qstring" under "Value", then selected "Change value display format" -> "Treat all characters as printable"