# How to access the complete value of string variables when debugging in qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt, ide, qt-creator

I'm debugging my c++ application and I have some string variables which can have 2000 characters or more. When debugging, the variable's value is shown incomplete (ending with "...") instead of showing the correct value. Also when I right click the variable and select "Copy current VALUE to clipboard" it is also copied incomplete. I think this must be a very basic thing but I didn't found in qt creator how to show the actual complete content of the variable? Thanks in advance.

In *Tools -> debugger -> Locals & Expressions* I've already changed the "maximum string length" and "display string length" to values above 10.000 but it is still only showing 500 characters.

Comment: For me, the limits set in settings work. If I use "copy current value to clipboard", it copies the string limited by "display string length" setting. Note that you  have to reload values in debugger window if you change the settings. I'm using 4.5.0.

Comment: I'm on 4.1.0, maybe it is the outdated version

Answer (score 7):

In *Local and Expressions*, right click on the variable and click on *Change Value Display Format*, then under **Change Display for type QString** click on *Separate Window*

Comment: I am using the "Separate Window" display, because by default Creator ends longer strings with "..." , even when I copy the value to the clipboard (which feels kinda buggy to do). 
But sometimes, the option to show a variable in a separate windows just disappears, I did not yet find out why and how to bring it back. Creator 4.8.2